# Keep getting NotFoundException: Invalid Method identifier specified error on aws_api_gateway_method_response object

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I reviewed similar topics on this issue with deploying an API Gateway via terraform onto AWS. Tried adding **depends_on** and sleep/delay of a few seconds as suggested by many, but was not able to resolve this issue with "Invalid Method identifier specified".

When I create the API Getaway resource manually in AWS, the response is created by default when I add the POST method.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

*Error: **Error creating API Gateway Method Response: NotFoundException: Invalid Method identifier specified**
│
│   with aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200,
│   on main.tf line 131, in resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200":
│  131: resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {*

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.gateway_resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.api_method_post.http_method   
  status_code = "200"   

  response_models     = {
        "application/json" = "Empty"
  }  
}
```

Comment: In these cases, it's recommended to enable `debug/trace` & check REST call fired to AWS APIs.. The resource may not be firing requests in the format expected by the API..

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon API Gateway API is particularly sensitive to what order you create all of the objects that relate to a resource, and will sometimes return confusing errors like this if you don't get the correct order. I think this error appears if you try to create the "method response" before creating the integration.

If I'm right about that (which I'm afraid I haven't been able to verify, since I don't currently have active AWS credentials to test with) then I think you could fix it by changing your `http_method` argument to refer to the integration's HTTP method instead, thereby telling Terraform to create the integration first and *then* create the method response:

```
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_integration.example.http_method
```

I used `aws_api_gateway_integration.example` because your example doesn't include your `resource "aws_api_gateway_integration"` block; you'll need to use the resource name you declared, instead of my `example` placeholder.